# Apply Style to Button Based on Property in XAML

Tags: wpf, xaml

**EDIT:**
Maybe I'm over complicating things by trying to swap styles since really the only thing I want is to be able to use different background images based on the status of the boolean property. The question should be more... **How can I use a background image to a button based on the status of the boolean property?**

I have two styles that animate and swap images when a mouse is over on a button, the styles work fine but what I want is to be able to use one of the styles based on the status of a Boolean property. Something like... `If property equals true, use style1 otherwise use style2`.

Here is my code:

### Animations:

```
     <Storyboard x:Key="MouseOverStoryboard" Duration="00:00:00.5">
        <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="image1" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" To="0" Duration="00:00:00.3" />
        <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="image2" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" To="1" Duration="00:00:00.3" />
    </Storyboard>

    <Storyboard x:Key="MouseLeaveStoryboard" Duration="00:00:00.5">
        <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="image1" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" To="1" Duration="00:00:00.3" />
        <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="image2" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" To="0" Duration="00:00:00.3" />
    </Storyboard>
```

### Style1:

```
    <Style x:Key="Style1"
           TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
        <Style.Setters>
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                        <Grid>
                            <Image x:Name="image1" Source="Images/image.png" Stretch="None" />
                            <Image x:Name="image2" Source="Images/image-hover.png" Stretch="None" Opacity="0" />
                            <ContentPresenter />
                        </Grid>
                        <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                            <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver"
                                     Value="True">
                                <Trigger.EnterActions>
                                    <StopStoryboard BeginStoryboardName="MouseLeaveStoryboard" />
                                    <BeginStoryboard Name="MouseOverStoryboard"
                                                     Storyboard="{StaticResource MouseOverStoryboard}" />
                                </Trigger.EnterActions>
                                <Trigger.ExitActions>
                                    <StopStoryboard BeginStoryboardName="MouseOverStoryboard" />
                                    <BeginStoryboard Name="MouseLeaveStoryboard"
                                                     Storyboard="{StaticResource MouseLeaveStoryboard}" />
                                </Trigger.ExitActions>
                            </Trigger>
                        </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style.Setters>
    </Style>
```

### Style2:

```
    <Style x:Key="Style2"
           TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
        <Style.Setters>
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                        <Grid>
                            <Image x:Name="image1" Source="Images/image2.png" Stretch="None" />
                            <Image x:Name="image2" Source="Images/image-hover2.png" Stretch="None" Opacity="0" />
                            <ContentPresenter />
                        </Grid>
                        <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                            <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver"
                                     Value="True">
                                <Trigger.EnterActions>
                                    <StopStoryboard BeginStoryboardName="MouseLeaveStoryboard" />
                                    <BeginStoryboard Name="MouseOverStoryboard"
                                                     Storyboard="{StaticResource MouseOverStoryboard}" />
                                </Trigger.EnterActions>
                                <Trigger.ExitActions>
                                    <StopStoryboard BeginStoryboardName="MouseOverStoryboard" />
                                    <BeginStoryboard Name="MouseLeaveStoryboard"
                                                     Storyboard="{StaticResource MouseLeaveStoryboard}" />
                                </Trigger.ExitActions>
                            </Trigger>
                        </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style.Setters>
    </Style>
```

### Applying Styles

```
    <Button x:Name="MyButton"
            Command="{Binding ButtonCommand}">
            <Button.Style>
                <Style TargetType="{x:Type Button}" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type Button}}">
                    <Style.Triggers>
                        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding SomeBooleanProperty}" Value="True">
                            <Setter Property="Style" Value="{StaticResource Style1}" />
                        </DataTrigger>

                        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding SomeBooleanProperty}" Value="True">
                            <Setter Property="Style" Value="{StaticResource Style2}" />
                        </DataTrigger>
                    </Style.Triggers>
                </Style>
            </Button.Style>
    </Button>
```

### ERROR Message:

> > Style object is not allowed to affect the Style property of the object to which it applies.

What I'm I missing?

Answer (score 2):

I don't believe that's the way to do this. You could set your styles in code behind, but a better way is to get rid of Style2 and combine with Style1 like this:

```
<Style x:Key="Style1"
       TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
    <Style.Setters>
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                    <Grid>
                        <Image x:Name="image1"
                               Source="Images/image.png" Stretch="None" />
                        <Image x:Name="image2"
                               Source="Images/image-hover.png" Stretch="None"
                               Opacity="0" />
                        <ContentPresenter />
                    </Grid>
                    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                            <Setter TargetName="image1" Property="Source"
                                    Value="Images/image2.png"/>
                            <Setter TargetName="image2" Property="Source"
                                    Value="Images/image-hover2.png"/>
                            <Trigger.EnterActions>
                                <StopStoryboard BeginStoryboardName="MouseLeaveStoryboard" />
                                <BeginStoryboard Name="MouseOverStoryboard"
                                                 Storyboard="{StaticResource MouseOverStoryboard}" />
                            </Trigger.EnterActions>
                            <Trigger.ExitActions>
                                <StopStoryboard BeginStoryboardName="MouseOverStoryboard" />
                                <BeginStoryboard Name="MouseLeaveStoryboard"
                                                 Storyboard="{StaticResource MouseLeaveStoryboard}" />
                            </Trigger.ExitActions>
                        </Trigger>
                    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style.Setters>
</Style>
```

And then you can just write:

```
<Button Style="{StaticResource Style1}"/>
```

Done.

Comment: And how would I evaluate the status of the `SomeBooleanProperty`?

Answer (score 1):

You can't set the `Style` property of en element in a `Setter` of a `Style` that is applied to the same element. That's basically what the error message tells you.

You could either use a single `Style` and use triggers with conditions in the `Style` to make it look different depending on the value of the `SomeBooleanProperty` property, or you could use a converter:

```
class StyleConverter : DependencyObject, IValueConverter
{
    public Style Style1 { get; set; }

    public Style Style2 { get; set; }

    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        bool b = (bool)value;
        return b ? Style1 : Style2;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotSupportedException();
    }
}
```

**XAML:**

```
<Button x:Name="MyButton" Content="Button" Command="{Binding ButtonCommand}">
    <Button.Style>
        <Binding Path="SomeBooleanProperty">
            <Binding.Converter>
                <local:StyleConverter Style1="{StaticResource Style1}" Style2="{StaticResource Style2}" />
            </Binding.Converter>
        </Binding>
    </Button.Style>
</Button>
```

Comment: I'm having issues using the converter. Would you mind demonstrating how would you do it using triggers in the Style?

Comment: @fs_tigre: You don't use it in a Style. You use it exaclty as I have demonstrated in my answer, i.e. the converter returns one style or another.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I ended up doing that worked with a single style.

```
 <Style x:Key="Style1" TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding SomeBooleanProperty}" Value="False">
                    <Setter Property="Template">
                        <Setter.Value>
                            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                                <Grid>
                                    <Image x:Name="image1" Source="Images/image.png" Stretch="None" />
                                    <Image x:Name="image2" Source="Images/image-hover.png" Stretch="None" Opacity="0" />
                                    <ContentPresenter />
                                </Grid>
                                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                                    <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                                        <Trigger.EnterActions>
                                            <StopStoryboard BeginStoryboardName="MouseLeaveStoryboard" />
                                            <BeginStoryboard Name="MouseOverStoryboard" Storyboard="{StaticResource MouseOverStoryboard}" />
                                        </Trigger.EnterActions>

                                        <Trigger.ExitActions>
                                            <StopStoryboard BeginStoryboardName="MouseOverStoryboard" />
                                            <BeginStoryboard Name="MouseLeaveStoryboard" Storyboard="{StaticResource MouseLeaveStoryboard}" />
                                        </Trigger.ExitActions>

                                    </Trigger>
                                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                            </ControlTemplate>
                        </Setter.Value>
                    </Setter>
                </DataTrigger>

                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsCSomeBooleanPropertyurrentPage}" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="Template">
                        <Setter.Value>
                            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                                <Grid>
                                    <Image x:Name="image1" Source="Images/image2.png" Stretch="None" />
                                    <Image x:Name="image2" Source="Images/image-hover2.png" Stretch="None" Opacity="0" />
                                    <ContentPresenter />
                                </Grid>
                                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                                    <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">

                                        <Trigger.EnterActions>
                                            <StopStoryboard BeginStoryboardName="MouseLeaveStoryboard" />
                                            <BeginStoryboard Name="MouseOverStoryboard" Storyboard="{StaticResource MouseOverStoryboard}" />
                                        </Trigger.EnterActions>

                                        <Trigger.ExitActions>
                                            <StopStoryboard BeginStoryboardName="MouseOverStoryboard" />
                                            <BeginStoryboard Name="MouseLeaveStoryboard" Storyboard="{StaticResource MouseLeaveStoryboard}" />
                                        </Trigger.ExitActions>

                                    </Trigger>
                                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                            </ControlTemplate>
                        </Setter.Value>
                    </Setter>
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
```